# Error: Variable was not declared in this scope!? C++

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement

This is my code (main.cpp) -

```
void InstallFlag();

int main()
{
    char a;
    cout << "Would you like to proceed with the installation setup? Y/N : ";
    cin >> a;

    if (a==Y) 
    {
        InstallFlag(); 
    }
    else {
        return 0; 
    }
}

void InstallFlag()
{
    //Setup code here
}
```

I get this error:
Error, Y was not declared in this scope.
Newbie to C++ :D

Comment: Looks like you're trying to write C program like a .bat file (labels, goto). 'goto' is considered harmful, so you'd better avoid it. Instead of 'goto Exit' you could write 'return 0', and instead of 'goto InstallFlag' you could use function call

Comment: Read a good C++ book before attempting to program.

Comment: Thanks @KirillGamazkov

I'd ignore others. :)

Comment: And btw, why are goto statements considered harmful?

Comment: Just trying out. Like I said, newbie. :)

Comment: goto is harmful because it's easy to lose track of control flow if there are about a dozen of them. Google knows more

Comment: Oh and the new code that you've proposed, is it safe to use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When you use some variable in your program,you need to declare it**,let your variable is a `char` type so you declare it like **char Y;** and when you initialize it with some value then we say that we defined it like **Y='A';**

**In your case the problem is** you have to put quotes around Y,like

```
if (a=='Y')
```

because your compiler is thinking that `Y` is variable which has not been declared yet, so the error.But when you will type quotes,it will consider it as a `character literal`

Answer (score 2):

You should compare answer with char, and now you are comparing with undefined variable.
So, your code should be like:

```
if (a=='Y')
//your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple. a == 'Y'. Y is variable name, 'Y' is char literal. You didn't define Y variable, compiler is right

Comment: Y isn't a variable actually. It's the user's choice. Can even be N.
So what do I do now?

Comment: As I've said, replace "a == Y" with "a == 'Y' || a == 'y'" and you'll be fine

Answer (score -1):

Your code should look like this

```
void InstallFlag();

int main()
{
    char a;
    cout << "Would you like to proceed with the installation setup? Y/N : ";
    cin >> a;

    if (a=='Y') 
    {
        InstallFlag(); 
    }
    else {
        return 0; 
    }
}

void InstallFlag()
{
    //your code 
}
```